# Check if $var1 OR $var2 values are found in string AND if $var3, $var4 and $var5 is in the same string

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I'm having issues with this following preg_match:

```
if (preg_match("[/$fnc1/|/$fnc2/]", $val) && (preg_match("[/$rank_1/|/$rank_2/|/$rank_3/]", $val) ===1)){ do something }
```

What I'm trying to achieve is: Check if `$fnc1` OR `$fnc2` is in `$val` AND if `$rank_1`, `$rank_2` OR `$rank_3` is in `$val`.
I've tried multiple times to  seperate/change the markups inbetween variables in the preg_match, but it does not work. I never end up with a positive result, even tho it works just fine if i replace the variables with text instead...

any tips?

Working code, no variables used:

```
if (preg_match("[\b123\b|\b456\b]", $val) && (preg_match("[\bACB\b|\bZXY\b]", 
$val) ===1)){
```

Comment: Why do you compare only the second time ?

Comment: Can you add some valid and invalid samples?

Comment: It should work, please give more context.

Comment: @Toto
if (preg_match("[\b123\b|\b456\b]", $val) && (preg_match("[\bACB\b|\bZXY\b]", $val) ===1)){ }

This code works, but when I use variables instead it does not...

Comment: Do not add code in comments, edit your question.

Comment: What are the slashes for in your regex?

Comment: Give some input strings, valid and invalid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you add unwanted square brackets and slashes in your regex, have a try with:

```
if (preg_match("/$fnc1|$fnc2/", $val) && preg_match("/$rank_1|$rank_2|$rank_3/", $val) ) {...}
```

You can combine the 2 preg_match into 1:

```
if (preg_match("/^(?=.*(?:$fnc1|$fnc2))(?=.*(?:$rank_1|$rank_2|$rank_3)).*$/", $val) ) {...}
```

Comment: That did the trick... Unwanted square brackets and slashes did mess it all up.